# Aligning avatar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using avatar in matierial UI, but nothing it working to align the avatar.

```js
export const CallerInformationCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <Card {...props}>
      <CardHeader
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
        avatar={
          <Avatar
            alt="John Snow"
            sx={{ height: "180px", width: "180px", alignSelf: "center" }}
            src={jonSnow}
          />
        }
      />
      <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        Jon Snow
      </Typography>
      <Typography subtitle1="h1" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        (412) 891-2312
      </Typography>
      <CardContent>
        <Stack>
          <Property label="Address" value="123 Elm Street" />
          <Property label="Checking Account Number" value="12352314" />
          <Property label="Savings Account Number" value="1234567890" />
          <Property label="Investment Account Number" value="9876543210" />
          <Property label="Customer Since" value="March, 2015" />
        </Stack>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

I have tried to align by using justifyContent within CardHeader and as well as alignSelf:"center"

SOLUTION:

```
<CardHeader 
   sx={{
       flexDirection: "column"
   }}
...
```

Comment: Make certain the width of the card header is 100% the width of the card.

Comment: it is. I checked with adding a background

Comment: You are severely limiting the pool of CSS experts able to answer the question to those familiar with React and willing to create a runnable example for understanding the problem and testing potential solutions. If you want to increase the number of people willing to provide a useful answer I suggest you create a *runnable* [mcve] (using codensandbox.io or a similar service). You might also want to tag the question `CSS` as that's the primary expertise required here. Think of tags as ways to call upon people who are proficient in that technology. Not as descriptors of your project.

Comment: My apologies Tao for doing the minimum I just wanted people with react experience to point me to right direction. I added a flexDirection: "column" to my cardHeader and that aligned the Avatar.

Comment: @Paul, I wanted you to be aware it was a [CSS issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) and you could have benefited from not limiting the number of people who could have helped to strictly those who knew React. Happy to hear you were able to sort it out by yourself. No need to apologise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the Avatar in the centre of the CardHeader. use a Box component to achieve this

```
import { Card, CardContent, CardHeader, Avatar, Typography, Stack, Box } from '@mui/material';

export const CallerInformationCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <Card {...props}>
      <CardHeader
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
        avatar={
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Avatar
              alt="John Snow"
              sx={{ height: '180px', width: '180px', alignSelf: 'center' }}
              src={jonSnow}
            />
          </Box>
        }
      />
      <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Jon Snow</Typography>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>(412) 891-2312</Typography>
      <CardContent>
        <Stack>
      <Property label="Address" value="123 Elm Street" />
      <Property label="Checking Account Number" value="12352314" />
      <Property label="Savings Account Number" value="1234567890" />
      <Property label="Investment Account Number" value="9876543210" />
      <Property label="Customer Since" value="March, 2015" />
    </Stack>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: There was no change

Comment: sorry mistakenly happen. I have edited the code. @PaulBlart